# Can't match multi-line HTML code read from a web page

Tags: java, html, regex

This is the HTML code:

```
         <td class="foobar" id="12345POE46" data="more &amp; data">
               <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" more="{data}">Value</a>                    </td>
```

Now, I'm not new to regex, but I am new to regex in Java. The only thing that I can't figure out is how to use this regex in Java, which is the one I use to extract the value from the code:

```
(?s)<td class="foobar".*?<a.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?</td>
```

I need the `(?s)` because there are newlines between the `<td>` and the `<a>`.

From what I've researched, all I need to do in Java is pass the `DOTALL` parameter to the pattern compile function:

```
p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

and then this regex should work:

```
<td class="foobar".*?<a.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?</td>
```

because the DOTALL parameter should behave like the `(?s)` flag.

But it isn't working. I searched for a while but couldn't find out what's wrong with that.

---

This is how I read the HTML code:

```
URL web = new URL(webURL); 
URLConnection gate = web.openConnection(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gate.getInputStream()));
String inputLine = in.readLine();
```

---

**Update:**

- I tested the same code with my regex and it works perfectly in all the online regex testers I've tried (with the `(?s)` flag).
- I wrote all my code in Python, everything identical, and it works perfectly with the `(?s)` flag, when I put the same string from the webpage HTML I index through Java.

Comment: Have you tried and googled for "regex html"? And read the first link? Use JSoup.

Comment: I know what's wrong with regex & html combination, and believe me, in my case it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, to each his poison so I may as well have a go... Is that your _full_ input? What do you use for matching? `.find()`?

Comment: I tried it with either `(?s)` in the pattern or `Pattern.DOTALL` as the second parameter to `Pattern.compile`, and either way it seems to work. I used the `matches` method of `Matcher` to check if it matches, what are you using?

Comment: I am using basically the same thing: `if (match.find()) listA.add(match.group(1));`. I did however change the code a bit because I didn't want to include private data, so I think that's why it works for you. I'll check what might be different.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I edit the question with the exact same format of my code - I just changed some words. It doesn't work for me in Java, but it does in my code editor when using the `(?s)` flag.

Comment: DOTALL and `(?s)` are equivalent, only another notation; meaning that `.` also matches any Unicode newline character.

Comment: I went over my code so many times, I can't find what's wrong. when I put the code in my editor the regex (with `(?s)`) matches, but when I use it in Java (with `DOTALL`) it doesn't. I use many other regular expressions in my program, but this is the only one that I need to match across multiple lines and it's the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: I just copied all my code to Python, and it works perfect. It must has something to do with Java and matching regex across newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original version with the `(?s)` should work perfectly fine, since Java [supports match flags](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special). You don't need DOTALL if you specify the flag inline.

**Update:** If your pattern isn't matching, it's for some other reason. This code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchFlags {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "foo\nbar";
        System.out.println(s.matches("foo.bar"));
        System.out.println(s.matches("(?s)foo.bar"));
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("foo.bar", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(s);
        System.out.println(m.matches());
    }
}
```

produces this output:

```
false
true
true
```

As you can see, either the `(?s)` inline flag or the `DOTALL` flag will cause the wildcard to match line feeds.

Further, the sample you gave works fine if you add a terminating `</td>` to it:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchFlags {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in =
            "<td class=\"foobar\" id=\"12345POE46\" data=\"more &amp; data\">\n" +
            "    <a href=\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\" more=\"{data}\">Value</a>\n" +
            "</td>";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile("(?s)<td class=\"foobar\".*?<a.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?</td>")
                .matcher(in);
        System.out.println(matcher.find());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

produces:

```
true
Value
```

Comment: It doesn't work when I only add `(?s)`, doesn't work when I only use the `Pattern.DOTALL` parameter, and doesn't work when I use both or none of them.

Comment: You're right, your code worked fine for me also when I put the real HTML code in the `in` string. It still won't work when I get the exact same string from the webpage using `URL web = new URL(webURL);
     URLConnection gate = web.openConnection();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gate.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine = in.readLine();` and read the HTML line by line. Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: It depends a lot on what happens after your `in.readLine();`. My guess would be you're searching in the wrong string. Why not just print out the string you're doing the match on and compare it with what you expect?

Comment: You're right, it's simply because I read one line a t a time so it can't match a regex that's aimed for multiple lines. That's why it worked for me in Python, because I didn't read the HTML line by line. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex appears to be working fine to me, I used the following code to test:

```
String s = "  <td class=\"foobar\">\n"
         + "\n"
         + "        <a href=\"http://www.webaddress.com\">Value</a>        </td>\n";
String regex = "<td class=\"foobar\".*?<a.*?>(.*?)</a>.*?</td>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found a match!\n");
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/geoLlA